# Why all subgroups of order 2 of Alternating group A5 are conjugate?

Tags: finite-groups, sylow-theory

By Sylow Theorem, all Sylow p-subgroups of $A_5$ are conjugate, for any $p\in \{ 2,3,5\}$.

But why  all subgroups of Alternating group A5 of order 2 are conjugate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* The elements of order $2$ in $S_n$ are the products of disjoint transpositions. What are the elements of order $2$ in $A_5$?

Comment: I don't know exactly.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @M.Ramana, here are two: $(12)(34)$, $(24)(35)$. Can you prove that they are conjugate?